# MySQL changing numbers per batch

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have table with column like this:
`id (int auto inc primary), title (varchar), batch (int)`
which characteristic is having 3 item per batch. But in this case the batch is not in sequence

Here the sample data:

- 1,a,5
- 2,b,5
- 3,c,5
- 4,d,7
- 5,e,7
- 6,f,7
- 7,g,10
- 8,h,10

Is there any query to update those batches become like auto increment? (order by batch) So batch 5 become 1, batch 7 become 2, batch 10 become 3 and so on.

TL;DR: I want to update sequence per batch, not per row

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
UPDATE t
JOIN (
SELECT
t.*,
@newbatch := IF (@rc % 3 = 0, @newbatch + 1, @newbatch) AS newbatch,
@rc := @rc + 1
FROM t
, (SELECT @rc := 0, @newbatch := 0) var_init_subquery
) sq ON t.id = sq.id
SET t.batch = newbatch;
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f629da/1/0)

If you have questions about how this works, please read this [manual entry about user defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) first.

Comment: Wow I can't believe there is a way..Thank you very much sir for the reference, i'll learn user defined variables that you provide.